# Error calling Webservice, when changing IP address in IIS from * to specific

Tags: web-services, iis, web, webexception

I have a site with a couple of application setup, that was working correclty that is hosted on a client server, but the client wanted to change the IPaddress in the binding from *(All unassigned) to a specific IP address.

Since then when the application A call the webservice that is in Application B (so using the same Ip address) I receive the error :

*Exception information: 
    Exception type: WebException 
    Exception message: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.*

If I revert back the Ip address from the specific one to the *(All unassigned) one it work as expected.

My question is : Is it valid to have one IP address in this case, or should it be revert back to * ?

[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the hostfile on the server, there was the issue in the hosts file that was causing a reference to the local internal IP address instead of the name of the site.

Changing it to the right IP fixed the issue.